# Change filename in Django Pisa

Tags: django, pdf, filenames, pisa

I wanted to render a template to a pdf file. So I looked this, and found the following code:

```
def write_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(
        html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='UTF-8')


    if not pdf.err:
        return http.HttpResponse(result.getvalue(),
                                 mimetype='application/pdf', )
    return http.HttpResponse('Gremlins ate your pdf! %s' % cgi.escape(html))
```

It works perfectly, but I am not able to change the filename.
If I start the download of this file, firefox says "1.pdf" is downloaded.
So here is my question:
How can i change the filename of the rendered template?
I looked this up, but I haven't found an answer.. (maybe I'm just too stupid^^)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You just need to set the `Content-Disposition` of your response:

```
def write_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(
        html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='UTF-8')

    if not pdf.err:
        response = http.HttpResponse(result.getvalue(),
                                 mimetype='application/pdf')

        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=whatever.pdf'

        return response
    return http.HttpResponse('Gremlins ate your pdf! %s' % cgi.escape(html))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!
Works perfectly
Thank you very much!